# Python Paramiko listdir in multi-hopped SSH

Tags: python, regex, ssh, paramiko, listdir

How can I listdir in multi-hopped ssh situation? Or there's other way to get my target file?

```
def file_lookup():
    for file in os.listdir('/var/log/rsyslog/firewall-a/'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'syslog-'+date+'-\d{10}\.gz'):
            global log_file
            log_file = file

def copy_from_log_server_to_bastion():
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.load_host_keys('/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts/')
    ssh_client.connect(bastion_ip, bastion_port, username, password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('scp ' + username + '@' + log_server_ip + ':' + logs_directory + log_file + ' ./')
    stdin.write(password)

def copy_from_bastion_to_local():
    # some codes here
```

I want my script to copy a file from remote server -> bastion host -> local, but I'm having problem with this multi-hopped ssh.

Here's the network-mapping:
(https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/22d200f8670dbdb3e253a90eee5098477c95c23d/2017/11/15/NM_diagram_061316_a1.png)

Sorry that I have not enough reputation to append image in post.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl nested ssh isn't my problem, my problem is how can I listdir under nested ssh...

Comment: If nested is SSH is not your problem then show us your current code for nested SSH and we can help you to do the listing. The code that you have posted does not do any nested SSH.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd modified my second function code into this, third function is unnecessary, and now it works:

```
def copy_from_log_server_to_local(log_client):
    os.mkdir('/vagrant/Logs/' + datetime.today().strftime('%m%d'))    
    scp_client = SCPClient(log_client.get_transport())
    scp_client.get('/var/log/rsyslog/firewall-a/'+log_file, '/vagrant/Logs/' + datetime.today().strftime('%m%d') + '/')
    scp_client.close()
```

`log_client` has channel opened with my bastion host